# Create character with Images in Box2D on iOS

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I have images of a character including (head,leftarm, rightarm, body,leftleg,rightleg etc).. I want to join these images to create a character like ragdoll. There is tutorial of joining the body parts but, I am not able to do this with images and sprites.

Can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yannick Loriot wrote a tutorial here: http://yannickloriot.com/2011/06/box2d-ragdoll-example-for-cocos2d/

The blog post points to the working source code for the app: https://github.com/YannickL/Box2D-Examples